# How to set layout_span through code

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow, layoutparams

Does anyone know how to set/change the `android:layout_span=""` of an EditText in Android at runtime. 
I already have the EditText defined in my XML file.

```
<TableRow android:paddingTop="20dip" android:gravity="center_horizontal">  

    <EditText android:layout_width="150dip" 
         android:text=""
         android:layout_height="40dip" 
         android:id="@+id/p"
         android:layout_span="2">
    </EditText>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams)editText.getLayoutParams();
params.span = toSpan;
editText.setLayoutParams(params); // causes layout update
```

Comment: but where it is stating that the layout_span = 2?? if I want to make layout_span=3 or layout_span=4?? then?

Comment: params.span = toSpan; You can assign your span value either 2 or 3 or 4 to toSpan variable

TextView txtView;
params.span = 4;
txtView.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: Nice, and there I was looking all over for a function that would return the span. Hidden in plain sight!