# How to set layout_weight attribute dynamically from code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

How can I set the value for the attribute `layout_weight` for button in android dynamically from java code ?

Comment: It'll be very similar to this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638832/how-to-programmatically-set-the-layout-align-parent-right-attribute-of-a-button-i/4639012#4639012 and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637233/how-to-set-layout-span-through-code/4637266#4637266

Comment: If you have already defined view in layout(xml) file, then creating new LayoutParams overwrites other params defined in xml file. So first you should use "getLayoutParams". See full answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code/38011495#38011495

Answer (score 553, accepted):

You can pass it in as part of the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` constructor:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    1.0f
);
YOUR_VIEW.setLayoutParams(param);
```

The last parameter is the weight.

Comment: It should be `param = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) 1.0);`

Comment: If you don't want to cast from a double to a float just put 1.0f

Comment: Or even simpler put `1f` if there are no decimal places

Comment: what to do if parent layout is `Relative`

Comment: @pratik if parent layout is relative you don't use weights

Comment: I think, one of two parameters LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT should be changed to 0.

Comment: @Erich Douglass: Thanks. Working properly for me. I have used same as you mentioned above. I am using this to divide screen in 2 parts horizontally.

Comment: @Erich what if i want to set 52% of weight, i have tried 0.52f, but it's not working

Comment: If all you want to do is change the weight of an existing view use parameters: view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height, <your wight here>

Answer (score 132):

Use [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

EDIT: Ah, Erich's answer is easier!

Comment: Erich's anser may be easier to write, but yours is easier to read. Since it says which attribute the 1.0f is used for.

Comment: yours established that you can modify weight on the fly by calling 'view.getLayoutParams()' then modify the value.

Comment: `FILL_PARENT` has been deprecated and `MATCH_PARENT` should be used instead.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Unfortunately many of us need to use `FILL_PARENT` still to support older versions of Android, and in the end, they both defined as the constant -1 for use in the layout.  Since `MATCH_PARENT` can cause errors in older Android, in many cases it is easier to just continue to use `FILL_PARENT`

Comment: @LocalPCGuy Not true. As long as you're *targeting* SDK >= 8 (which you absolutely should be), `MATCH_PARENT` can be used instead of `FILL_PARENT` even on older devices.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy [No one uses API 7 or less anymore](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). If you're trying to make your app compatible with APIs 7 or less, you'd probably run into a whole lot of other problems before worrying about `FILL_PARENT` vs. `MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: Good point.  I actually ran into it on an app that was originally designed to be compatible with those versions, and so had to maintain that compatibility.  Guess I just never looked at exactly where the cutoff was.

Answer (score 94):

If you already define your view in your layout(xml) file, only want to change the weight programmatically, this way is better

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)   
mButton.getLayoutParams();
params.weight = 1.0f;
mButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

new a LayoutParams overwrites other params defined in you xml file like margins, or you need to specify all of them in LayoutParams.

Comment: With "params.weight = 1f;" you're already setting the weight on the LayoutParams object. There's no need to call "mButton.setLayoutParams(params);".

Comment: No, you have to call setLayoutParams

Comment: This is actually the most elegant answer and it directly changes a specific UI object. The best answer is good too and older than this post. So it deserves as the best answer. I upvoted this post though.

Comment: Great and simple solution!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You don't have to call setLayoutParams. I've just tried it out.

Comment: You can actually just call `mButton.requestLayout()` instead `setLayoutParams` since you're just changing a value. `setLayoutParams` calls `requestLayout` internally.

Answer (score 33):

If the constructor with width, height and weight is not working, try using the constructor with width and height. And then manually set the weight.

And if you want the width to be set according to the weight, set width as 0 in the constructor. Same applies for height.
Below code works for me.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
childParam1.weight = 0.3f;
child1.setLayoutParams(childParam1);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
childParam2.weight = 0.7f;
child2.setLayoutParams(childParam2);

parent.setWeightSum(1f);
parent.addView(child1);
parent.addView(child2);
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Every one is talking about setting weights here, no one displayed what happens when those weighed Children are added to the Parent View! I was actually looking for how to add weightSum on the ParentView! Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

If `layoutparams` is already defined (in XML or dynamically), Here's a one liner:

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams()).weight = 1;
```

Comment: Underrated answer

Answer (score 14):

If I someone looking for answer, use this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lay = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) myLayout.getLayoutParams();
lay.weight = 0.5;
```

If you are initializing your layout from xml file, this will be much more convenient than providing new layout parameters for Linear Layout.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it doesn't modify any previously set variables like width/height/margin/padding etc. Everything is being kept and re-used while the weight is changed.

Comment: If the view to set `layout_weight` has already been laid out, you need to call `View.requestLayout()` to update.

Answer (score 8):

Any of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `TableLayout.LayoutParams` worked for me, for buttons the right one is `TableRow.LayoutParams`. That is:

```
            TableRow.LayoutParams buttonParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
```

About using `MATCH_PARENT` or `WRAP_CONTENT` be the same.

Comment: `FILL_PARENT` has been deprecated and `MATCH_PARENT` should be used instead.

Comment: I think LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT should be changed to 0.

Comment: You call the `LayoutParams` of the direct parent. I assume you had a crash attempting to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` without the parent `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have **already defined your view in layout(xml) file and only want to change the weight** pro grammatically, then then creating new LayoutParams overwrites other params defined in you xml file.

So first you should use "getLayoutParams" and then setLayoutParams

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mButton.getLayoutParams();
 params.weight = 4f;
 mButton.setLayoutParams(params);`

Answer (score 3):

I have done my task by adding this line of code!

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mylayout = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)   
myview.getLayoutParams();
mylayout.weight = 2;
myview.setLayoutParams(mylayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Kotlin you can do something like:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView
import android.widget.*

import android.widget.LinearLayout

class RespondTo : CardView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {


        val parent = LinearLayout(context)

        parent.apply {
            layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f).apply {
                orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL

                addView(EditText(context).apply {
                    id = generateViewId()
                    layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.9f).apply {
                    }
                })
                addView(ImageButton(context).apply({
                    layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f)
                    background = null
                    setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_save_black_24px))
                    id = generateViewId()
                    layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
                        addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT)
                        // addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, myImageButton.id)
                    }
                }))
            }
        }
        this.addView(parent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set weight to LinearLayout then use code mentioned below or set weight to Relative Layout then replace it with Relative Layout

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
1.0f
```

);
YOUR_VIEW.setLayoutParams(param);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.
First, you get the LayoutParams associated with this Button. Perform a type conversion.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
```

Then assign the required value of the "weight" parameter.

```
linearLayoutParams.weight = 5;
```

Redraw the layout.

```
button.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in Kotlin:

```
val params = mButton.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
params.weight = 1.0f
mButton.layoutParams = params
```