# Set weight (percentage) programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got two buttons that I'd like to dynamically weight give a preference.  They start out each with a weight of .5 (which of course adds to the LinearLayout's weight of 1), but if the preference is true, then I'd like to change their weights to .7 and .3 respectively.  I can set the weight in XML but I can't seem to find how to change it programmatically.

---

**Solution**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams PO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .60f);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams MO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .20f);
```

Comment: Check my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code#answer-13943330

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html), it has a field for setting the weight

Comment: Yop, I ended up with:

` LinearLayout.LayoutParams PO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .60f);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams MO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .20f);`

Comment: @ecirish I added your solution to tail of question, for better visibility

Answer (score 3):

Use this to recycle the `LayoutParam` object:

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).weight = 0.2f;
view.refreshDrawableState(); // This is to explicit force the refresh.
```

Answer (score 3):

If the constructor with width, height and weight is not working, try using the constructor with width and height. And then manually set the weight.

And if you want the width to be set according to the weight, set width as 0 in the constructor. Same applies for height.
Below code works for me.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
childParam1.weight = 0.3f;
child1.setLayoutParams(childParam1);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
childParam1.weight = 0.7f;
child2.setLayoutParams(childParam2);

parent.setWeightSum(1f);
parent.addView(child1);
parent.addView(child2);
```