# Add 7 buttons dynamically to adjust all the screen sizes to it's width and height in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I want to add buttons dynamically according to diffrent screen sizes. How can I achive it.

This is what I have tried. But when I change the first button from WRAP_CONTENT to static height, width none of the button is shown on the screen

```
public void setButtons(){
    // button one params
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(380,433,10,20);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getMyNewX(76),getMyNewX(76));
    params1.setMargins(229,-45,50,20);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getMyNewX(76),getMyNewX(76));
    params2.setMargins(239,60,10,20);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getMyNewX(76),getMyNewX(76));
    params3.setMargins(422,-45,10,20);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getMyNewX(76),getMyNewX(76));
    params4.setMargins(592,-455,10,20);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params5 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getMyNewX(76),getMyNewX(76));
    params5.setMargins(592,65,10,20);

    //   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params6 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(76,76);
    //     params6.setMargins(592,-275,10,20);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    Button button1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    button1.setLayoutParams(params);
    // button1.setText("like");
    button1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.like));
    // button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Button button2 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    button2.setLayoutParams(params1);
    //    button2.setText("share");
    button2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.share));
    //      button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Button button3 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    button3.setLayoutParams(params2);
    //    button3.setText("mute");
    button3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mute));
    //      button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Button button4 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    button4.setLayoutParams(params3);
 button4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.download));


    Button button5 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    button5.setLayoutParams(params4);
    button5.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


    Button button6 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    button6.setLayoutParams(params5);
    button6.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


    layout.addView(button1);
    layout.addView(button2);
    layout.addView(button3);
    layout.addView(button4);
    layout.addView(button5);
    layout.addView(button6);

    buttonLayout.addView(layout);

}

 originalWidth = 1100;
    originalHeight = 2050;

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;


}


 int getMyNewX(int originalX)
{
    //originalX : x for line segment
    return width/originalWidth * originalX;
}
int getMyNewY(int originalY)
{
    //originalY : y for line segment
    return height/originalHeight * originalY;
}
```

Comment: Use weightSum of linearlayout

Comment: how and where to use it ?

Comment: Please add more context to your question. Why do you need to add these buttons dynamically and not in the XML?

Comment: @ArulHarsh Check this for [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18940741/3117966)

Comment: add your height and width to dimen it is better   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(R.dimen.button_width,R.dimen.button_width);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29713797/5154783

Answer (score 0):

You can add weight dynamically this way

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: you need to set as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio

```
res -> values -> dimens.xml
```

[image]

declare your dimensions for devices below w820dp in dimens.xml file

[image]

dimension for devices w820dp and above  in dimens.xml(w820dp) file

[image]

then use it in your code like

[image]

Android will automatically select required sizes for different resolutions

```
**w820dp - for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This
         would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively).**
```

[this may also help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution .

**Solution 1**:convert dp to pixel

```
private int convertPxToDp(int px){
return Math.round(px/(Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi /DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

Now you have dynamic value of pixel for all screen size.

**Solution 2**:Add weight to all your button

If it is vertical orientation then

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);`

else

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

And then

```
params.weight = 1.0f;
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use layoutparams with weight property to fix width equally. Find below code.

```
private void initViews() {
    lytButtons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lytButtons);
    btnAddButtons = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddButtons);

    btnAddButtons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addButtons();
        }
    });
}

protected void addButtons() {
    try {
        Button btn1 = createButton("Btn 1");
        Button btn2 = createButton("Btn 2");
        Button btn3 = createButton("Btn 3");
        Button btn4 = createButton("Btn 4");
        Button btn5 = createButton("Btn 5");
        Button btn6 = createButton("Btn 6");


        lytButtons.addView(btn1);
        lytButtons.addView(btn2);
        lytButtons.addView(btn3);
        lytButtons.addView(btn4);
        lytButtons.addView(btn5);
        lytButtons.addView(btn6);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Button createButton(String text) {

    Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
    btn.setText(text);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams prm1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    prm1.weight = 1.0f;
    btn.setLayoutParams(prm1);

    return btn;
}
```