# How to set child weight in the code?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want that button(child) will have 25% of full width of horizontal LinearLayout (its parent). The code:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
ll.setWeightSum (1.0f);

Button b = new Button (this);
ll.addView(b);
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENTS,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    lp.weight = 0.25;
    b.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in as part of the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` constructor:

```
LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
```

Comment: Hi infinity. I think I begun to get the idea of the LayoutParams. Thanks.

Comment: @tatiana_c - if 'infinity's' answer worked for you, please be sure to mark the answer as accepted so that we can all benefit.

Comment: Hi Garry, do you mean to choose "yes" button in the question if it was useful for me? I am an new user in this site, Thanks.

Comment: Garry, hi again. My question is not relevant any more, in other my post there are somebody explained me about. I'll do. Thanks.