# how to completely remove a view and use its space in android

Tags: java, android, width, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

So in my android app I have two Linear Layouts side by side with the same weight & width 
One is called "LeftView" another called "RightView" 
what I like to do is removing RightView and giving all the space assigned to it to LeftView ...with a click of a button while the app is running
So in the end LeftLayout becomes bigger obviously 
How to achieve this guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set that LinearLayout weight to `0`. I just tried that and it works for me. Here is how you can do it:

[How to set layout_weight attribute dynamically from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code)

Comment: I've already set them to 0 and they're even by size ...
but the problem is how to dispose of the rightview ...visually and
programatically ! ( I mean literally killing its object)

Comment: yes, you set your layouts how you like, then programatically get layout using findViewById and use link I gave to you to set layout's weight to 0.

Comment: ow sorry ... I kept mistaking weight for width... 
you were right homie !
Another solution I found was RightLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);