# Layouting android fragments programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am new to android development and currently struggling with fragments and layouts (Xamarin.Android for what it's worth).

I am adding fragments to my View programatically in the OnCreate method of my main view. One of the fragments holds the controls for navigation and implements a fly-over Idiom. Now my problem is, that I haven't found a way to make the width of the navigation fragment, say, half of the width of the parent control. In every override I have been able to access the layout has not been performed and hence the width of the fragments and the main view are both 0. Setting the size of the fragments decleratively in the layout files did not work either (neither for the translate properties which I'll nees to access in the same way to hide the fragment initially). Xamarin/VS complains that setting the size or translate properties to a string (i.e. parent_width or the like) was not valid.

Every tutorial on fragments I've read omits this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem correctly you are having an issue with layout sizing of fragments added dynamically.

It may be helpful if you were able to paste your code outlining how you are adding your fragments and what override methods you attempted to use. However, here is a best attempt to assist without seeing any code.

There are two approaches to sizing dynamically added elements that I have used in the past consistently. One is to use a base container for your layout of LinearLayout and specify weights for your fragments dynamically. This would allow you to specify that your fragments should consume portions of the layout easily. For instance if you have fragment A and B and you wish for fragment A to consume 25% of your layout space - you can set its weight to 1 and Fragment B's weight to 4. You can find support for dynamically setting weight of an element (such as your fragment) here: [How to set layout_weight attribute dynamically from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code)

Another option would be to use the an OnGlobalLayoutListener that will "fire" when the control is laid out. This will ensure when you try to measure the layout to determine its width/height that it has already laid out and consumed the proper space for measurement and you will not get back 0. There are a number of articles outlining how to write up the code for this listener scattered throughout the web. I It may also be useful to subclass out some of the listener functionality for easy reuse if you find you have a need often to know when the control has laid out. Here is a link to the Android documentation on the subject http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The (I)OnGlobalLayoutListener did the trick for me. Thank you very much.