# Dynamically change weight of an ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have a Linear Layout inside a Relative Layout in the LinearLayout i have Two image buttons which have weight 50 each, i want to set the weight of one ImageButton to 100 using java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set layout\_weight attribute dynamically from code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to set `weight` dynamically

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imagebutton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = 1.0f;
imagebutton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Refer this for more details [How to set layout_weight attribute dynamically from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4641072/2809326)

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

p.weight = 1;   
imagebutton.setLayoutParams(p);
```