# Android: hide an element

Tags: android, element, visibility

imagine an Android app that has 3 TextViews in a linear layout, one sequentially below the other, then 2 buttons. 1 button needs to hide the second text view, and the second button needs to make it visible again.

The only **requirement is that when the second text view goes away, it should not occupy any space**, meaning that third text view should occupy its space while it is gone.

I tried this with the INVISIBLE and VISIBLE settings, however, a blank placeholder remains in the place of the second text view.

I tried with GONE, which eliminated the blank space, however I could not make the second text view appear again.

Do you know a way to achieve this?

Example:

```
////////////////////////////
initial state:
textview1
textview2
textview3
button1
button2

--> user pushes button1

new state:
textview1
textview3
button1
button2

--> user pushes button2

new state: initial state
////////////////////////////
```

Thanks

Comment: `I tried with GONE, which eliminated the blank space, however I could not make the second text view appear again.` You have to re-set its visibility to VISIBLE.

Comment: How did you try to make it appear? You should set its visiblity to Visible again

Comment: you can also visible GONE texView again by setting visibility.

Comment: try `android:layout_weight="0"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: @MehranZamani how to do this from the java code?

Comment: [last parameter is weight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Two ways:

**XML**

in your XML file. If you want to have initial visibility

```
android:visibility="gone" <-- hides
```

or

```
android:visibility="visible" <-- makes it visible
```

**Java**

in java file. For when you need to change it programmatically

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);//makes it disappear
```

or

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//makes it visible again
```

---

Different visibilities:

- Visible

Says itself: Sets the view to be visible

- Invisible

Hides the view, but it still occupies space.

- Gone

Hides the view, and makes it occupy no space.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, you can set like this

```
textView.visibility = if(visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

or you can add the extension on View

```
fun View.setVisible(visible: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (visible) {
        View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        View.GONE
    }
}
```

the use it like this

```
textView,setVisible(true)
```