# android : using weight to textviews for linearlayout in java file

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

Is there any way of generating weight to textviews for linearlayout in java file.

> This is the code im using but its not alligned properly

**java file:**

```
LinearLayout afternoonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.afternoonLayoutId);

    if(afternoonSession !=null && afternoonSession.size() >= 0){

        TextView txtAfternoon = new TextView(this);
        txtAfternoon.setText("Afternoon");
        txtAfternoon.setTextSize(22);
        txtAfternoon.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        txtAfternoon.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        txtAfternoon.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        if(afternoonSession.has("Vitals")){

            txtAfternoonVitals = new TextView(this);
            txtAfternoonVitals.setText("Vitals " + "- " + "                      " + afternoonSession.get("Vitals").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            txtAfternoonVitals.setTextSize(16);
            txtAfternoonVitals.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            txtAfternoonVitals.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }else{
            txtAfternoonVitals = new TextView(this);
            txtAfternoonVitals.setText("Vitals " + "- " + "                      " + "Not Done");
            txtAfternoonVitals.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            txtAfternoonVitals.setTextSize(16);
            txtAfternoonVitals.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            txtAfternoonVitals.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }

        if(afternoonSession.has("Lunch")){

            txtAfternoonLunch = new TextView(this);
            txtAfternoonLunch.setText("Lunch " + "- " + "                     " + afternoonSession.get("Lunch").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            txtAfternoonLunch.setTextSize(16);
            txtAfternoonLunch.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            txtAfternoonLunch.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }else{
            txtAfternoonLunch = new TextView(this);
            txtAfternoonLunch.setText("Lunch " + "- " + "                     " + "Not Done");
            txtAfternoonLunch.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            txtAfternoonLunch.setTextSize(16);
            txtAfternoonLunch.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            txtAfternoonLunch.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }

        if(afternoonSession.has("Oral Medication")){

            txtAfternoonOral = new TextView(this);
            txtAfternoonOral.setText("Oral Medication " + "- " + "    " + afternoonSession.get("Oral Medication").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            txtAfternoonOral.setTextSize(16);
            txtAfternoonOral.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            txtAfternoonOral.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }else{
            txtAfternoonOral = new TextView(this);
            txtAfternoonOral.setText("Oral Medication " + "- " + "    " + "Not Done");
            txtAfternoonOral.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            txtAfternoonOral.setTextSize(16);
            txtAfternoonOral.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            txtAfternoonOral.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }

        afternoonLayout.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        afternoonLayout.addView(txtAfternoon);
        afternoonLayout.addView(txtAfternoonVitals);
        afternoonLayout.addView(txtAfternoonLunch);
        afternoonLayout.addView(txtAfternoonOral);


    }
```

> I have alligned the code using blankspace, this is not the proper way
>   of doing since im getting different allignment in different mobile
>   versions

**Output needed:**

```
  Afternoon
  vitals            02:00pm 
  Lunch             03:00pm
  Oral Medication   04:00pm
```

> But i am getting unalligned textview in different mobile versions.Is
>   there any way of adding weight to java file.Since im doing string
>   concatination i am unable to use weights

This is the output i am getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auH8V.png)

Comment: Why don't you use recyclerview for this purpose and create a proper row with weights that will be easy for this requirement ?

Comment: You can also assign weights to each textView and just ensure that the width and height is both set to match_parent

Comment: Add third parameter to setLayoutParams  like this -    txtAfternoon.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));

Comment: @FarazAhmed : need to change logic as well, so its better to implement using this format

Comment: I think the guy needs more of a monospace font adjustment, than adjustment of the weights of the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set layout\_weight attribute dynamically from code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weights can adjust the textview to be with different heights. I seriously doubt that this is what you want.
If I understand your "align with blankspace", you are looking how to apply monospace font, so that the hours are aligned.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can  set `layoutweight` and `weightSum` from java code like below:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.afternoonLayoutId);
layout.setWeightSum(10F);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams(); 
//you can  create new LayoutParams too ...
layoutParams.weight = 0.5f;
txtAfternoonVitals = new TextView(layout.getContext());
txtAfternoon .setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Still it is not alligned properly. I tried  setting layoutweight and weightsum.

Comment: Since i am doing a string concatenation i am not able to allign properly