# How to set multiple scroll views size to change dynamically relative to each other?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have two scroll views in a vertical linear layout.
I want them to be relative to each other so that they fill the entire linear layout and compensate if one cant cover half the screen.

Lets call that scroll views TOP and BOT.
If the screen can display 4 rows and both scroll views have infinite rows, each scroll views should display 2 rows and be able to scroll down to se the rest rows.

If TOP has 1 and BOT infinite rows, BOT should be resized to 3/4 of the linear layout.

If TOP have infinite and Bot has 1 row TOP should still just display 2, i.e. it should never pass the linear layouts vertical center.

Here are some pictures for reference:

[image: my setup with weight set to 0.5/0.5]

my setup with weight set to 0.5/0.5.

[image: result of 0.5/0.5 weight. Notice the gray bar above the BOT title bar. This empty space should be filled by the BOT bar]
result of 0.5/0.5 weight. Notice the gray bar above the BOT title bar. This empty space should be filled by the BOT bar.

[image: if Using fixed size or wrap content the TOP will push the Bot out of view]
if Using fixed size or wrap content the TOP will push the Bot out of view.

How can I have them hugging each other and still set TOP to a maximal height?
Preferable in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to set the weight dynamically. Count the number of items in both views. Set the weight of each view according to the ratios of their number of items. You can refer [set weight dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code) for setting weights at run time