# How to set layout_weight programmatically?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-layout-weight

Disclaimer: AFAIK This question **has no answer so far for XAMARIN ANDROID**. It has been answered multiple times for [Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code).

My problem is that I have no constructor overload for GridLayoutParams that takes the layout_weight as a parameter...

The following is the XML I'm trying to replicate by code:

```
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Not setting layout_weight makes the control (a checkbox) simply invisible.

Here is where I am with the Xamarin Android code:

```
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.Id = View.GenerateViewId();
            GridLayout.LayoutParams cbButtonLayoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            cbButtonLayoutParams.RowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(row, 1);   // Setting row and rowspan respectivly
            cbButtonLayoutParams.ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(column, 1);    // Setting col and colspan respectivley
            cbButtonLayoutParams.Width = 0;
            cbButtonLayoutParams.Height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
            cbButtonLayoutParams.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
            // How do I set the weight ? There is no property nor constructor...
            // cbButtonLayoutParams.???
            cb.LayoutParameters = cbButtonLayoutParams;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Setting weight is only available on LinearLayout.LayoutParams. only if you try a cast, dont know if it works like that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's under the respective `Spec`.

```
cbButtonLayoutParams.RowSpec.weight = 1; //might be Weight in C#
cbButtonLayoutParams.ColumnSpec.weight = 1;
```

I'm not sure if you want the row weight or the column weight, but that's how you do it for both.

EDIT:

I believe that `InvokeSpec()` is equivalent to `spec()`, which means the second parameter *should* be the weight, as long as both parameters are `Int32`.

---

Also, `layout_weight` is usually only for when the parent of that element is a LinearLayout. Are you sure that the CheckBox is actually being added to the GridLayout and not a LinearLayout child?

Comment: The parent of the checkbox is a GridLayout. You are right there is an overload of InvokeSpec that takes a float as the second parameter which is the weight. I'll try that.

Comment: Works like a charm :)