# Horizontal/vertical spacing not working as they should on Android

Tags: android, gridview

This issue gave me a painful headache. Basically I have a `GridView`-based Gallery app. Everything is working fine. But I want to have equal spacing, that is horizontal and vertical, between the images, so it's easier to distinguish one from another.

This is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.gallery.MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridView gridView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullScreenAnimationAdapter.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the `ImageAdapter`'s `GetView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(ctx);
    imageView.setImageResource((int)getItem(position));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));
    return imageView;
}
```

So I have both `horizontalSpacing` and `verticalSpacing` set to `3dp`. Yet my application looks like this:

[image]

All the images are `1920x1080` and `96 dpi`.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Should I change some properties in the xml file, or maybe I should use a different `ScaleType` for my `ImageView`s?

Comment: Try change: `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));` to `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 240));` Hope that helps!

Comment: God damn, @I_A_Mok, it works! This should be an accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinearLayout with layout_weight attribute.

sudo code to help you with the idea.

```
<LinearLayout
layout_orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ImageViews are added dynamically, so I don't know if I can do that. First Android app btw, so I'm just asking

Comment: You can still use LinearLayout and add views dynamically. Make sure you set LayoutParams and add it to the LinearLayout.

Comment: Okay, so I can change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. But if I do only that, it doesn't help

Comment: layout_weight attribute is available only in LinearLayout. If you really need this attribute, you need to make the change.

Comment: I did it. But then how can I specify layout_weight for ImageViews if I don't have them in .xml file?

Comment: You would create ImageView in your java code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641117

Comment: Okay, now the spacing is equal, but the images are displayed like this: https://imgur.com/a/crmG9Zg

Comment: Don't use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, instead use LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, or use dp value.

Comment: I can only pass two ints for like width and height and then a float for weight. Are those implicitly treated as dp and not as pixels or something?

Comment: Did you try using WRAP_CONTENT? Yes, they are in px. You should convert them to dp https://stackoverflow.com/a/6327095

Comment: I did WRAP_CONTENT and it was no difference between MATCH_PARENT. Now I have something like this (you can see the changed code on the left hand side): https://imgur.com/a/AhD1vLm. Which is kind of strange, cuz now it's better I guess, but it's stil not equal spacing :(

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dabljues/1d50c45fad2c145fdccf1b1f3bdd26ed. Those FullScreen files (.java and .xml) I guess are irrelevant, but I've included them as well just in case

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentiond way:

```
In Activity java:

for set space:
  mGridView.setHorizontalSpacing(4);
  mGridView.setVerticalSpacing(4);

for get Spacing:

 mGridView.getHorizontalSpacing()
 mGridView.getVerticalSpacing()


In XML
<GridView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"     
android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
```