# How to create a horizontal list view or recycler view with fixed size by changing the width of its items

Tags: android

I'm beginner in Android Development and trying to create a display of items in such a way that the size of these varieties according to the quantity, as they have done in this app. Any suggestions?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6H4B.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH9xK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager​.​HORIZONTAL​, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById​(​R​.​id​.​my_recycler_view​);

myList​.​setLayoutManager​(​layoutManager​);
```

Answer (score 0):

So according to your question you have to add weight to the child elements which you can be given from parent layout like ex: recyclerview weight 3, and its item weight 1 each(if you have 3 items and fit in the width with margins on either sides) and consider to assign 3 to 6 elements in the width of the screen with horizontal scrolling

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

check here how to set weights for the views [How to set layout_weight attribute dynamically from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code)