# programmatically code for layout_weight for ImageView in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I want to set **programmatically** **Layout_weight** for imageview with **kotlin** code for be sure layout_weight not weightsum LIKE THE CODE BELOW

```
    fun stack(x:Int){
        
        
        LinearLayout1.weightSum= 1F
        imageView1.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        imageView2.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        imageView3.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        if (x==1) {
            imageView1.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            imageView1.layout_weight=1F  ***//I want this***
            imageView2.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
            imageView3.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else if (x==2){
            imageView1.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
            imageView2.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            imageView2.layout_weight=1F    ***//I want this***
            imageView3.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else if (x==3){
            imageView1.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
            imageView2.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
            imageView3.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            imageView3.layout_weight=1F  ***//I want this***

        }
        
    }
```

---

Comment: Sounds like a good goal. Can you show what you've tried so far and where you are stuck? [help] on Asking Good Questions

Comment: I added LinerLayout weight sum of it is 1
and I added six imageView in it so I want to change the layout_weight of imageVeiw when image1 visible layout weight = 1 and when image2 visible  layout_weight of image1 = 0 and  layout_weight of image2 = 1

Comment: can you add the layout code to the question?

Comment: I did it **door is an ImageView

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set layout\_weight attribute dynamically from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code)

Comment: No dear :) it's java not kotlin and it's for linerlayout not for ImageView

Comment: I need for kotlin and for ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This:

```
var params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    1.0f
)
imageView1.setLayoutParams(params)
```

in this line: `var param = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(`
We are using `LinearLayout` because your image view is inside a `LinearLayout`

Comment: When I did it he convert the code to
                                          
 `var params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        1.0f
                    )
imageView1.layoutParams { params }`

and the last code send me wrong in word `layoutParams `of `imageView1.layoutParams { params }` the message is

Expression 'layoutParams' of type 'ViewGroup.LayoutParams!' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Comment: Use      = params     not. {params}

Comment: I know it dear , but the problem is I must us                             `imageview1.setLayoutParams(params)` it works with `setLayout....` thanks a lot dear

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer so it easier for other people to find in the future