How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found?
I have the following code witch i partly got from my teatcher and then aded some parts myself:
This is my MainActivity.Java. I removed the api string but i know it is correct as I have tested it in postman
package com.example.foodstore;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier; import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection; import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext; import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession; import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager; import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager; import java.security.KeyManagementException; import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; import java.security.SecureRandom; import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VolleyCallback {

    //Alla globala variabler
    ScrollView sV;
    LinearLayout pll;
    ArrayList<Product> Products = new ArrayList<>();

    //API nyckeln
    String key = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });


        //Hämtar ut de element som ska hanteras
        sV = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        pll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.productLayout);

        /*Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(),1024*1024);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        RequestQueue requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        requestQueue.start();*/

        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024*1024);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        RequestQueue requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        requestQueue.start();

        //Full api sträng för att hämta ut produkter, limit är 10
        String apiString = "" + key;


        Log.e("", apiString);

        //Skapar en instans av funktionen InternetConnection för att se om vi har uppkoppling
        /*InternetConection internetConection = new InternetConection(getApplicationContext());

        //Kollar om vi inte har någon uppkoppling och visar en Toast med felmedelande
        if(!internetConection.isConnectcted()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "404! No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{


        }*/

        APICall apiCall = new APICall();
        apiCall.get(requestQueue,this, apiString);

    }

    //Knappen för att visa alla kategorier
    public void category(View view){

    }

    //Knappen för att visa kundkorgen
    public void cart(View view){

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject object) {
        try {

            Log.e("", "fetch");
            JSONArray products = object.getJSONArray("products");

            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++){
                String name = products.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString();
                String category = products.getJSONObject(i).get("category").toString();
                double price = Double.parseDouble(products.getJSONObject(i).get("price").toString());

                //Skapar ett objekt utifrån klassen Food med värden från API:et
                Product product = new Product(name, category, price);

                //Lägger till objektet i listan food
                Products.add(product);
            }

            //Log.e("", "Antal produkter: " + String.valueOf(Products.size()));

            for(int i = 0; i < Products.size(); i ++){
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                ll.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

                TextView tW = new TextView(this);
                tW.setTextSize(20);
                tW.setText(Products.get(i).getName());
                ll.addView(tW);

                TextView tW2 = new TextView(this);
                tW2.setTextSize(15);
                tW2.setText("Category: " + Products.get(i).getCategory());
                ll.addView(tW2);

                TextView tW3 = new TextView(this);
                tW3.setTextSize(12);
                tW3.setText("Price: " + String.valueOf(Products.get(i).getPrice()) + "kr");
                ll.addView(tW3);

                Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setText("add to cart ");

                //Sätter params för knappen
                //Från tråden https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641072/how-to-set-layout-weight-attribute-dynamically-from-code
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);

                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 128, 0));
                btn.setPadding(10,0,0,0);
                ll.addView(btn);

                pll.addView(ll);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("", "Error onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Faild to fetch data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


This i my APICall.java
package com.example.foodstore;

import com.android.volley.*;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class APICall {

    public void get(RequestQueue requestQueue, VolleyCallback callback, String url){
        //public void get(RequestQueue requestQueue, MainActivity callback, Activity2 callback2, Activity3 callback3, Activity4 callback4, String url){
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                callback.onSuccess(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                callback.onFailure(error);
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}

The problem is that i have to build it in API levl 24 but every time I run it I get an error form the APIcall class that says "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found." But when I change to API level 26 it works
My appManifest.xml looks like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FoodStore"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

And my buidl.gradle.kit (app:) looks like this
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.foodstore"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.foodstore"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    implementation (libs.volley)

}

Anyone that knows why?


Anyone that knows why?

Your Web server is using an SSL certificate that is not supported on older Android devices. For example, Let's Encrypt certificates do not support Android 7 and older devices.

So i ned a newer emulator? I use an Nexus One Emulator now, should I try a newer phone? My teatcher use that one and it works for him and I have to use it for my school asignment

@Daniel: "I use an Nexus One Emulator now" -- the hardware profile in the Android Studio emulator simply describes things like screen resolution and density. It does not force you into specific versions of Android.

Allrigt, my projekt must work for API level 24 (Android 7) how can I set up an emulator for that?

@Daniel: "my projekt must work for API level 24 (Android 7)" -- that may require changes to the server, which will be out of scope for this Stack Overflow question.
