# how to set layout_span, layout_margin dynamically in code in android

Tags: android-layout

how to set layout_span, layout_margin  dynamically in code in android

Comment: This problem was simple solved here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637233/how-to-set-layout-span-through-code

Answer (score 6):

You can set layout_margin with a `TableRow.LayoutParams` instance given to `TableRow.addView()`:

```
TableLayout newTable = new TableLayout(DisplayContext);
int rowIndex = 0;

// First Row (3 buttons)
TableRow newRow1 = new TableRow(DisplayContext);
newRow1.addView(new Button(DisplayContext), 0);
newRow1.addView(new Button(DisplayContext), 1);
newRow1.addView(new Button(DisplayContext), 2);
newTable.addView(newRow1, rowIndex++);

// Second Row (2 buttons, last one spans 2 columns)
TableRow newRow2 = new TableRow(DisplayContext);
newRow2.addView(new Button(DisplayContext), 0);
Button newButton = new Button(DisplayContext);

// Create the layout to span two columns
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
params.span = 2;
newRow2.addView(newButton, 1, params);

newTable.addView(newRow2, rowIndex++);
```